# Setting Configurable product select options

Tags: javascript, configurable-product

I have the following requirement. Shop sells varnish with litres/sheen product variations. However, not every product will have same attributes - a 5ltr can may have two sheen options, a 10ltr can may only have one sheen.

1. When a user selects a gallery image of a 5lt can it should

   a. change the main product image to 5 ltr
   b. change the litres selection option to '5'
2. When the user uses the select to change the litres, it should update the main product image

I have the main functionality sorted for 1 & 2, but I can't control the 'sheen' select - if I enable it the product sheen options are not firing in sync with the size changes. Hopefully you could see in the attachment what I mean (if I was allowed to post one!) - the second select is stuck on 'Select an Option', whereas it should be populated with options. Nor does changing the gallery images update the sheen select.

The code I have is as follows:

```
<div class="product-img-box">
   <p class="product-image product-image-zoom"><img id="image" src="" alt="Bona parent" title="Bona parent" /></p>
</div>

<div class="more-views none-slider-more-views">
    <ul id="img-list"> 
      <li> <img class="changer" data-main-image-src=""  src="" alt="5" title="5"  /></li>
      <li><img class="changer" data-main-image-src=""  src="" alt="0.75" title="0.75"  /></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

The Javascript is being deployed in template/product/view/media.phtml & uses JQuery to retrieve the clicked image & substitute, using the image alt as a map between the image & the Litre options, is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('.changer').click(function()
    {    
        jQuery("#image").attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("data-main-image-src"));
        var divid = jQuery(this).attr("alt");
        changeSelectState("#attribute990");
        jQuery("#attribute989 option").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).html() == divid) {
            jQuery(this).attr("selected", "selected");        
            return;
        }
       });  

    });
    jQuery("#attribute989").change(function(){

         jQuery("#attribute989 option").each(function () {
         changeImage(jQuery('#attribute989 :selected').text());
         changeState();
         return false;
       });  
    });
    function changeImage(obj){
        jQuery('.changer').each( function(idx,img) {
         var pAlt = img.alt;
         if(obj == pAlt)
            jQuery("#image").attr("src", jQuery(this).attr("data-main-image-src"));
        });
    }
    function changeSelectState(obj){
         changeState();
         //jQuery(obj).attr('disabled', false);

    }


});
  function changeState(){
    // simulate firing a DOM event
    if (typeof fireEvent !== 'function') {
        document.fireEvent = document.createEventObject ? // IE
        function(element, event) {
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on' + event, evt);
    } : // FX
        function(element, event) {
            var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
            evt.initEvent(event, true, true); // event type, bubbling, cancelable
            return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
        };
    }
    // preselect the 1st option of the 1st-maxPreselectedAttributeOptionCount
    window.maxPreselectedAttributeOptionCount = 2;
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        if (!spConfig) {
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(maxPreselectedAttributeOptionCount, spConfig.settings.length); ++i) {
        var attr = spConfig.settings[i];
            attr.selectedIndex = 1;
            Event.observe(attr, 'change', Prototype.emptyFunction);
            fireEvent(attr, 'change');
            spConfig.reloadPrice();
        }
    });
  }
```

This issue comes when simulating the user selecting an option from the Litres dropdown. I'm sure I'm doing something very wrong here! Any suggestions most welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Still unsolved?

I use this on a site to select the first configurable option, which triggers the 'change' event, which populates the second select for me.

Hopefully you can use/adapt it to your usage case.

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  // Once dom has loaded, grab the first select option (Business rules say there will always only be 1 - this is the product colour)
  // ...select this option and set as true. Triggers 'change' event for size option select to work/enable/populate.

  var options = $$('.super-attribute-select');
  var len = options.length;
  var qty = $$('#qty');
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(options[0][1]){
      options[0][1].selected = true;

      triggerEvent($$('.super-attribute-select')[0],'change');
    }
    // Always selects 1
    if(qty[0]){
      qty[0][1].selected = true;
    }
  }

});


// Custom prototype function to fire an event
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype
function triggerEvent(element, eventName) {
  // safari, webkit, gecko
  if (document.createEvent)
  {
    var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    evt.initEvent(eventName, true, true);

    return element.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }

  // Internet Explorer
  if (element.fireEvent) {
    return element.fireEvent('on' + eventName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old post but maybe this helps.
I developed this FREE extension: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher that should do what you need.
It will replace the dropdowns with simple product images (for the attributes you decide) and allows you to set a default configuration for the configurable products.
If it does not do exactly what you need, at least you can take a look at the js file and see how to manually trigger `select` changes.